# Hide Contact Form 7 and show DIV after Sent

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I want to hide my Contact Form 7 after validation and a successful sent, and show a div in its place.  I'm using the shortcode ID. Its not working. Would it be easier to wrap the form in a div and hide that instead?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event) {
    if ( '9a5f5ae' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
        var hid = document.getElementsByClassName("qtWRP2");
        if(hid[0].offsetWidth > 0 && hid[0].offsetHeight > 0) {
            hid[0].style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
}, true );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to hide the form (and the custom div). Just add the following to your CSS:

```
.qtWRP2 {display: none;}
.wpcf7-form.sent p { //remove the p if you want to hide the confirmation box displayed by C7 as well
  display: none;
}
```

And then change the visibility of the custom div that you have like this:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('.wpcf7').addEventListener('wpcf7submit', () => {
    const c7form = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form');
    const hid = document.querySelector("#test");
    if (c7form.classList.contains('sent')) {
      hid.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Then how do how I show the DIV message after validation and the form is sent?

Comment: Okay, but .qtWRP2 is showing under the form.  How do I hide it before submit?

Comment: <div class="qtWRP2">
<div class="qtWRP2">Thank you. We received your TUBSAFE quote request, and a member from our team will contact to help you get started with your bathroom project.
</div> I need to hide this unti the form is sent.

Comment: @Erik Add `.qtWRP2 {visibility: hidden;}` to your CSS and let the JavaScript code above show it when the form is submitted.

Comment: Here is the ink:  https://tubsafeusa.com/  Still does not work.

Comment: Appreciate the try

Comment: Sorry, does not work.

Comment: So C7 has custom events and one of them is `wpcf7submit`. Can you try replacing the above line yet again but with this: `document.querySelector('.wpcf7').addEventListener('wpcf7submit', () => {`

Comment: @Erik I have tested the above on a C7 form and it's working now. Check the updated code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Very grateful.  Using visibility does not hide the element but keeps it in pace using up space.

Comment: qtWRP2 needs to be "display:none" to "display:block"

Comment: Here is my css: .qtWRP2 {visibility: hidden;}

.wpcf7-form.sent p {
  display: none;
}
.qtWRP2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}

Comment: I added an image to show you using "visibility" does not hide the DIV

Comment: @Erik Then simply replace visibility with display (block/none) in the CSS and JavaScript as shown in the edited code above.

Comment: @Erik Did replacing `visibility` with `display` as shown above work for you?